# Jsxgraph circle dragging of its body area

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

I am new to JsxGraph. My usecase is to drag circle with its body or area, that is dragging from inside of its Circumference or area. I found all of jsxgraph Circle event like drag, mousedown etc,work only when we click over its Circumference border and do not fire when click inside the circle.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circles can be constructed with the attribute `hasInnerPoints` which does exactly this.

Example:

```
var circ = board.create('circle', [...], {hasInnerPoints: true});
```